# Recover files after moving directory names?

Tags: shell, data-recovery

During the course of some testing, I ran the bast script

```
for file in *; do
    mv -v "$file" "$file#_*"
done
```

or something along those lines.  The plan was to remove a prefix from  directory names but I accidentally ran it in my home directory rather than in the test directory I had created...

My understanding is that all of the files inside directories should be "safe" (as in, not deleted), but that I now have no way to access them via a directory structure.

Is there a way to recover these files?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** It appears my memory was incorrect: the command in the `for` loop was actually `echo mv ...`.  Somehow, all the directories and file in ~ were moved to my Videos directory, but appear to be intact.

Comment: what is the filesystem?

Comment: It's a standard Linux Mint install, so its ext3 I believe.

Comment: Were the (non-hidden) files all renamed with `#_*` appended to their name?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - no. Turns out they got moved them into `~/Videos` - there's a comment thread on it on my answer.

Comment: There's no such thing as “not deleted [but] no way to access them via a directory structure”. If the files aren't deleted, there's a way to access them — under their new name. Look at the script that you ran to see what these new names are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you did there, but if the command in your question is the one you ran, you should just be able to reverse it:

```
for f in *
do echo mv -v "$f" "${f%"#_*"}"
done
```

Please don't remove the `echo` from that command until you're sure it works, but, just to explain why I think it will, here's what I did:

```
for f in $(seq 100)
do echo $f > file$f
done
```

That made me 100 files like `file1` - `file100` and each one contained its number, so:

```
$ cat file100
100
```

Like that. Then I did your thing:

```
for f in *
do mv -v "$f" "$f#_*"
done
```

And I had a bunch of files like `file1#_*` - `file100#_*`. Then I did my thing pasted in the first codeblock here, but without the echo and I did...

```
$ cat file100
100
```

Comment: I think the problem with this is that when I do a `ls -a`, there are no files listed (beyond the ones with a . prefix, which were spared).

Comment: @Nick - then that is not the command you ran. What is? and what is the filesystem? And really - 0 files that don't begin with a .? Not just 1 file?

Comment: here's the copy paste of the code:
    `for file in * ; do
    echo mv -v "$file" "${file#*_}"
    done`

Apologies for poor formatting, I've never used the stack exchange before

Comment: @Nick - don't worry about the formatting. Please - what is the filesystem? That's the copy-paste? I think you're in luck! All you did was an echo, *if that's it*. That command is nerfed. So where did your files go? You should try to remember a name of at least one of them and do `sudo find / -name PUTTHATNAMEHERE`

Comment: You are correct!  Turns out there was one directory than survived whatever that script did: Videos.  Somehow, all of the directories/files in my home directory were moved into that one...  Thanks a ton for your help!

Also, since I'm currently doubting my competency...  Would the correct way to get the directories out of ~/Videos/stuffhere and put them in ~/stuffhere where they belong be mv * ../ from the Videos folder?

Comment: @Nick - just play it safe - stick to `cp`. Do this `mkdir -p ~/stuffhere ; cp -t ~/stuffhere ~/Videos/*` - that way you're just making copies.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help!  I think everything has survived okay!